# How to copy local files named with the destination server name?

Tags: ansible

How would you resolve this small script in ansible playbook ?

Files to copy are named `[ServerName].[extension]`
The destination server is `ServeName`

```
for file in $(ls /var/tmp)
do
    ServerName=$(echo $file | awk -F. 'NF{NF--};1'
    scp /var/tmp/$file $ServerName:/var/tmp/
    scp /var/tmp/pkg.rpm $ServerName:/var/tmp/
    ssh $ServerName "cd /var/tmp; yum -y localinstall  pkg.rpm "
done
```

Thanks for your help

The idea would be to have something like this (but working, of course)

```
- name: main loop
  copy:
     src: "{{ item }}"
     dest: "/var/tmp/myfile.json"
- name: Install package
   yum:        
     name: "packageToInstall"        
     state: present

  delegate_to: "{{ item.split('/')[-1][:-5] }}"

  with_fileglob:
      - "/var/temp/*json"
```

Comment: Are you trying to execute this script using Ansible or copying the script and execute in the destination server using Ansible?

Comment: I would like to create a playbook which does what the script does without having to launch any shell script

Comment: The idea would be to make something like this (but which would work, of course)                                                                                     - name: main loop
    set_fact:
      Servername: "{{ item.split('/')[-1][:-5] }}"
    copy:
       src: "{{ item }}"
       dest: "/var/tmp/myfile.json"
    delegate_to: "{{ Servername }}"    

    with_fileglob:
        - "/var/temp/*json"

Answer (score 0):

If you were to write this in yaml, you should use `ansible_hostname`, ansible already has several informations about the host via [setup](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/setup_module.html).

```
- name: copying files
  copy:
    src: /mine/file.ext
    dest: /etc/{{ ansible_hostname }}.ext
```

More about **copy** in [module description](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/modules/copy_module.html).
All facts gather during setup are available [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#information-discovered-from-systems-facts).

Comment: ansible_hostname is the name of the destination host.  In the flow I do not know its name yet.

Comment: "Files to copy are named [ServerName].[extension]. The destination server is ServeName", isn't that your objective? can you be more clear? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: ansible_hostname is the name of the destination host.  In the flow I do not know its name yet.  On our configuration server, there is a file system where the [ServerName].ext file arrives.  When it is there, it has to be copied to the server mentionned in the name of the file.  How could I assign  ServerName (collected from the file name) to hosts: ?

Comment: The idea would be to do something like this (but which would work, of course)
  - name: main loop
    set_fact:
      Servername: "{{ item.split('/')[-1][:-5] }}"
    copy:
       src: "{{ item }}"
       dest: "/var/tmp/myfile.json"
    delegate_to: "{{ Servername }}"    

    with_fileglob:
        - "/var/temp/*json"

Comment: Please, add formatted code to your question for better readability.